# Adding a dropdown field to a userform which populates data from API

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am setting up a userform and I want to dropdown field which gets its values from an external API. The dropdown field get the values and when I add it to the userform, the form submission goes to 500: Error. I was wondering if there is a procedure for this in Silverstripe

```
class TestDropdown extends EditableMultipleOptionField {

private static $singular_name = 'Test Dropdown Field';

private static $plural_name = 'Test Dropdown Fields';

/**
 * @return DropdownField
 */
public function getFormField() {    
    function testAPICall($method, $url, $data){
       $curl = curl_init();

       switch ($method){
          case "POST":
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
             if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
             break;
          case "PUT":
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
             if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
             break;
          default:
             if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
       }

       // OPTIONS:
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'api.authorization.key: xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbb',
          'Content-Type: application/json',
       ));
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

       // EXECUTE:
       $result = curl_exec($curl);
       if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
       curl_close($curl);
       return $result;
    }
    $get_data = testAPICall('GET', 'http://xxxxxx/yyy/zzzz', false);
    $optionSet =  json_decode($get_data, true);

    if($optionSet) {
        foreach($optionSet as $key => $value) {
            $options[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $field = DropdownField::create($this->Name, $this->Title, $optionSet);


    return $field;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact error message you're receiving?

Comment: Hi @Cheddam, It doesnt show any error even in the dev mode but just shows a white screen. The URL after form submission is /contact-us/user-defined-form/Form instead of /contact-us/new-user-defined-form/#success which is the confirmation for submission. It happens only when this field is added to the form.

Comment: The first thing you always do on a 500, is you go check the server’s error log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death (based on _“but just shows a white screen”_)

Comment: Smoothly done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The form action lead to white screen of death which is at this instance didn't create a log. So we figured out that this is to do with Silverstripe Userforms not handling the data from an external APi. My last resort was update to the latest version which fixed this issue. Thanks everyone.